# URL whitelist class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, url

I'm trying to make a class for safe redirection of URLs. Redirecting URLs is something you can have in a get parameter, for example:

```
http://localhost/login?return_url=/landing1
```

So the attacker can't change it to something external and even internal. I implemented it this way for a Rails project:

```
class SafeReturnUrl
  WHITELIST = [
    '/landing1',
    '/landing2'
  ].freeze

  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def to_str
    return nil if @url.blank?
    raise "Url #{@url} should be whitelisted" unless WHITELIST.include?(@url)
    @url
  end
end
```

An alternative implementation is to have Rails URL helpers, but in this case a whitelist can be initialized only when the class is initialized:

```
class SafeReturnUrl
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def initialize(url)
    @whitelist = [
      landing1_path,
      landing2_path
    ]
    @url = url
  end

  def to_str
    return nil if @url.blank?
    raise "Url #{@url} should be whitelisted" unless @whitelist.include?(@url)
    @url
  end
end
```

It's not very scalable and the price for that - the whitelistis  initialized every time when `SafeReturnUrl` is initialized.

I covered the first version with tests, but for my team it's not enough ("So unmaintainable"). I don't think it's unmaintainable, because it's covered with tests, and there is no performance penalty.

I'm not using `HashSet` here - it's another type of optimization. We'll add it when we'll have a list with more than 10 elements.

Which version looks better and is there any way it can be optimized?

Answer (score 2):

You could put the whitelist in an initializer since you're using Rails, then the whitelist is available globally.

```
WHITELIST = [
  '/landing1',
  '/landing2'
]
```

Then it would be possible in your `login` controller to do something like this:

```
redirect_to WHITELIST.include?(params[:return_url]) ? params[:return_url] : root_path
```

The downside would be that you need to restart your rails app if you need to update the whitelist.